# 2D Ball Stabilization Platform

Tags: opencv, image-processing, yolo, pid-controller

I am trying to do 2D ball stabilization platform which always keeps the ball which is put on the platform, center of the platform (x= 0, y=0).

Here is my restriction and requiements:

1. Resistive panel is not allowed
2. Platform at least 50cm x 50 cm
3. When applied any disturbance to ball, platform must stabilize it on the center within 10 seconds
4. Using **COMPUTER** is not allowed, a controller must be used
5. If image processing is used, using **READY FUNCTION** is not allowed (OpenCV etc. is allowed but such as function for detecting ball is not allowed, we have to write it)

I think that image processing is the best way for this project because when detect the ball I can easily apply PID control algorithm to platform. However, I have no idea about image processing and how to do it with controller.

I thought using laser distance meter but to precise measuring I have to use a lot of sensor which is expensive.

What can I do about this situation. Any link, help, datasheet, essay about this topic would be appreciated. If someone light my way I can make a progress easiliy.

Comment: all due respect to whoever imposes these restrictions on you but those restrictions are *dumb*, unless they want to make this needlessly difficult. video processing takes computational power. a raspberry pi could be considered a computer. microcontrollers have way too little processing power, especially for *video* processing. doing computer vision without any libraries is also dumb. there's no reason to write all the primitive functions from scratch. possible, yes. -- this problem merely needs a camera, some `cv::inRange()` and statistics (bounding box) on the largest connected component

Comment: Statement is like this: If image processing will be used, student have to write your own functions rather than using a ready function. What do you understand from this statement ? I understood that openCV or something like that is not allowed.

Comment: in your situation, I would discuss your approach with the instructor and ask them to clarify the restrictions. there is no single "ready function" that detects a ball. you'd build that from a few existing functions, as described above. if the instructor wants you to implement those functions yourself, that's still the same approach, just with extra work to show that you are able to write the code for these functions too. -- in any case, I think the core task is to implement a PID (or lesser) controller, reading sensors, controlling motors (simple servo motors probably easiest)

Comment: I see your point. I will talk my instructor and then write his response to hear. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: My instructor has indicated that using OpenCV is allowed. Now I think using raspberry pi and opencv but which raspberry is enough for image processing?

Comment: for this little bit of processing, they all should be ok, but the newer models are faster of course. -- if things run slow, just reduce the frame size. your application needs good frame rate more than it needs image resolution.